# Insert non duplicates when PHP multiple values insert in single query fails due to duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, duplicates

I have an application that generates multiple random numbers and inserts the same in MySQL database using the following code:

fielda is Primary key and fieldb is the 12 digit random key which has to be unique as a requirement and is set to unique in the DB.

```
$datafields = array('fielda', 'fieldb', 'created_on');

$data = array(value1a, value1b, 'now()',value2a, value2b, 'now()' ....valueNa, valueNb, 'now()');
```

where N(and variable $N) is total number of rows and is typically around 100,000 to a million for every insert in a table

```
function placeholders($text, $count=0, $separator=","){
    $result = array();
    if($count > 0){
        for($x=0; $x<$count; $x++){
            $result[] = $text;
        }
    }

    return implode($separator, $result);
}
$pdo->beginTransaction(); // also helps speed up your inserts.
for($i=0;$i<$N;$i++){
    $question_marks[] = '('  . placeholders('?', 7) . ')';

}

$sql = "INSERT INTO code (" . implode(",", $datafields ) . ") VALUES " . implode(',', $question_marks);
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
try {
    $stmt->execute($data);
} catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$pdo->commit();
```

I had the following questions on the above:

In my case I am inserting close to 100000 rows at a time. If I understand correctly and form the experiments I have run even if one row in the query has a duplicate for fieldb or fielda the whole query fails.

1) Is it possible to change this behavior and insert atleast those rows which are non duplicate and return the count of rows and the field values where a duplicate was found so that only those rows can be regenerated.  I want to do this to avoid checking in PHP for every code I generate if it exists in the DB or the new set of codes generated. I am inserting anywhere from 100000 to a million rows per instance and this DB is only going to get larger. My array_flip, in_array etc operations that I am using to search for duplicate values before insert are running out of memory with the large db and causing the application to crash and hence I want to avoid the duplicate check in PHP and instead do as above.

2) if the above is possible I want MySQl to return all the rows successfully inserted so that I can output this to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that insertion fails at MySQL level. To do so, you have to make the random number belong to a unique index, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE code (
    -- [...]
    UNIQUE INDEX fieldb_unique (fieldb)
);
```

This has the additional benefit of ensuring data integrity.

Once you have this, you'll see that failed insertions will throw a `PDOException`. For added robustness, you should check whether the [MySQL error code](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-messages-server.html) is `1062`:

> Error: 1062 SQLSTATE: 23000 (ER_DUP_ENTRY)
>
> Message: Duplicate entry '%s' for key %d
>
> The message returned with this error uses the format string for
>   ER_DUP_ENTRY_WITH_KEY_NAME.

```
list($sqlstate, $mysql_code, $message) = $stmt->errorInfo();
if ($mysql_code==1062) {
}
```